# Undefined method `belongs_to' when accessing new custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, rails-admin

I've added a new custom action to XslStylesheet, however when I try to access this, I get the following error:
`` undefined method `belongs_to' for #<RailsAdmin::AbstractModel:0x14fb614d> ``

I have done this once before already for another model, but I didn't encounter this error. I have tried completely copy-pasting that action and renaming it, however this hasn't helped.

New action (\rails_admin\lib\rails_admin\config\actions\xsl_action.rb):

```
  module Config
    module Actions
      class XslAction < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :collection do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get, :put]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            if request.get? # Show index page
              respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render @action.template_name }
                format.js   { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
              end

            elsif request.put? # UPDATE
              #save uploaded image to GridFS
            end
          end
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-list-alt'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

New action's view (\rails_admin\app\views\rails_admin\main\xsl_action.html.haml):

```
  %h1{:style => "padding-bottom: 1%; margin-top: 0px; padding-top:10px;"} Upload Asset
  = form_tag('/admin/xsl_sheet/xsl_action?'+'Application='+params[:Application]+'&Company='+params[:Company]+'&locale=en', method: :put, multipart: true) do
    = file_field_tag 'stylesheet'
    %br
    = submit_tag 'Submit'
```

I've added the following into rails_admin.rb:

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/xsl_action'

RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::XslAction)

xsl_action do
  only XslStylesheet
end
```

I've also tried wrapping `XslStylesheet` in square brackets, this didn't help.

Expected outcome is that clicking on the new tab redirects the user to xsl_action.html.haml through the asset_action action. I instead get `` undefined method `belongs_to' for #<RailsAdmin::AbstractModel:0x14fb614d> ``

It might be worth noting that the index page works as intended for this model.

Edit: XslStylesheet.rb Model

```
require 'mongoid/grid_fs'

class XslStylesheet
  include Mongoid::Document

  scope :companyId, -> {where(assetable_id: User.current_user.current_scope['Company']) unless User.current_user.nil? or User.current_user.current_scope.nil?}

  belongs_to :company
  validates_uniqueness_of [:data_file_name, :image_id], :scope => :assetable_id

  field :data_file_name, type: String
  field :assetable_id, type: Integer
  field :image_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
end
```

Comment: Weird i have my "only" with arrays, could you try that only [Asset] ?

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba I've tried 
`asset_action do
  only [Asset]
end` but this hasn't changed anything.

Comment: What does Asset.abstract_class return?

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba 
```[1] pry(#<RailsAdmin::MainController>)> Asset.abstract_class
NoMethodError: undefined method `abstract_class' for Asset:Class
from org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1657:in `method_missing'```

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba 

My Model looks like this: 
```class PictureAsset 
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :data_file_name, type: String
  field :data_content_type, type: String
  field :data_file_size, type: Integer
end```

It's not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base as I get
```Cannot create scope :page, because of existing method Asset.page.``` 
when starting the server if I do.

Comment: It seems that rails admin think you are ActiveRecord models. Could you add the line of the exception backtrace where it says which file raised the exception? it should be a path inside the rails admin gem.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Is this what you mean? ```app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb:150:in `block in check_scope_on_query'``` I'm still a bit illiterate in Rails

Comment: To debug this the hard way: you would inspect that line of code going backwards at the callers until you find what you need to configure to ensure mongoid compatibility with Rails Admin.